# Regular Expression replacing substring

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

It is available column like 'ABCURLCBSURLDMSURLWER' in a table. URL repeats in that column. I want to retrieve the statement between two URL like below.

```
Column
------
CBS
DMS
```

I wrote query such as below but the query I wrote wasn't retrieved the result that I wanted.

```
SELECT 
REGEXP_SUBSTR((SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('ABCURLCBSURLDMSURLALI','URL',','),'ABC',',') AS AB FROM 
DUAL),'[^,]+',1,LEVEL) AS AB
FROM
DUAL
CONNECT BY
REGEXP_SUBSTR((SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('ABCURLCBSURLDMSURLWER','URL',','),'ABC',',') AS AB FROM 
DUAL),'[^,]+',1,LEVEL)
IS NOT NULL;

AB
---
CBS
DMS
WER
```

How can i fix this query?

Comment: Just wonder, how comes URLs are stored that way?

Comment: I had to use something repetitive to give an example, so I used it :)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a query like this. Copying your solution to replace the `URL` text with a `,` makes the regex much simpler to split the string.

#### Updated Query

```
WITH some_data (ab) AS (SELECT 'ABCURLCBSURLDMSURLWER' FROM DUAL)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (REPLACE (sd.ab, 'URL', ','),
                      '[^,]+',
                      1,
                      lines.COLUMN_VALUE)    AS ab
  FROM some_data  sd,
       TABLE (CAST (MULTISET (    SELECT LEVEL     AS level_num
                                    FROM DUAL
                              CONNECT BY INSTR (sd.ab,
                                                'URL',
                                                1,
                                                LEVEL) > 0) AS SYS.odciNumberList)) lines
 WHERE lines.COLUMN_VALUE > 1;
```

#### Output

```
    AB
______
CBS
DMS
```

Comment: Unfortunately, The result is wrong. It retrieved  ABC and WE as result of this query as well.

Comment: @EJEgyed, the OP wants values between URLs only, i.e. `CBS` and `DMS`

Comment: This is wrong (apart from it doesn't do what the question asks) because `[^(URL)]` matches any one character that is not an opening round bracket `(` or `U` or `R` or `L` or a closing round bracket `)`. So if you had the input as `'URL(LUR)(LUR)URL'` then you would get no characters matched.

Comment: I have fixed the query so it should return proper results now.

Comment: If the string is `'ABCURLCB,SURLDMSURLWER'` this this only returns `CB` and `S` rather than `CB,S` and `DMS`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=92b6776e82f258972263ff69c6e0cc69)

Comment: bcdyzi has not given an indication that any non-alpha characters appear in the string so the solution should work for the example provided.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option; see comments within code:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    -- sample data
  3    (select 'ABCURLCBSURLDMSURLWER' from dual),
  4  rpl as
  5    -- replace URL with a semi-colon (a single/simple delimiter)
  6    (select replace(col, 'URL', ';') col
  7     from test
  8    ),
  9  rmv as
 10    -- remove everything in front of the 1st delimiter and everything after the last delimiter
 11    (select substr(col, instr(col, ';') + 1,
 12                        instr(col, ';', -1, 1) - instr(col, ';') - 1) val
 13     from rpl
 14    )
 15  select regexp_substr(val, '[^;]+', 1, level) result
 16  from rmv
 17  connect by level <= regexp_count(val, ';') + 1;

RESULT
--------------------
CBS
DMS

SQL>
```

Comment: If the string is `'ABCURLCB;SURLDMSURLWER'` then this returns 3 rows instead of 2. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0b0150af0819b8cbd942c120fe82bb7d)

Comment: Certainly, @MT0, but sample data says nothing about containing semi-colons within the string. On the other hand, it says nothing about NOT containing it either :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expressions and can do this with simple string functions:

```sql
WITH bounds ( id, value, start_pos, end_pos ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         value,
         INSTR( value, 'URL', 1, 1 ) + 3,
         INSTR( value, 'URL', 1, 2 )
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         value,
         end_pos + 3,
         INSTR( value, 'URL', end_pos + 3, 1 )
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  end_pos > 0
)
SELECT id,
       start_pos,
       SUBSTR( value, start_pos, end_pos - start_pos ) AS url
FROM   bounds
WHERE  end_pos > 0
ORDER BY id, start_pos;
```

So, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, value ) AS
SELECT 1, 'ABCURLCBSURLDMSURLWER' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'ABCURLURLDEFURLGHIURL' FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> ID | START_POS | URL 
> -: | --------: | :---
>  1 |         7 | CBS 
>  1 |        13 | DMS 
>  2 |         7 | null
>  2 |        10 | DEF 
>  2 |        16 | GHI
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=db6852fd9380d83d7f18895179531491)*

---

## Option 2

If you did want to use regular expressions then you can use:

```sql
SELECT t.id,
       x.COLUMN_VALUE AS url
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
                      t.value,
                      '(.*?)URL',
                      INSTR( t.value, 'URL' ) + 3,
                      LEVEL,
                      NULL,
                      1
                    )
              FROM  DUAL
              CONNECT BY
                     LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(
                                t.value, '(.*?)URL', INSTR( t.value, 'URL' ) + 3
                              )
           )
           AS SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST
         )
       ) x;
```

Which, for the same test data, outputs:

> ```
> ID | URL 
> -: | :---
>  1 | CBS 
>  1 | DMS 
>  2 | null
>  2 | DEF 
>  2 | GHI
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9253fe7d0880885de98e80d01b4636e8)*

Comment: Option 2 would not work if your `test_data` table had more than one row in it as you would get duplicated data.

Comment: @EJEgyed The OP only had a single row of input. However, that's an easy fix so I've updated it to handle multiple rows. Just take the query and `CROSS APPLY`/`CROSS JOIN` it to the multi-row input table inside a table collection expression.